# Mac: Mouse + click + hotkeys +/- drag?

Tags: mac

Ok, I've always struggled with organisation on Macs. Hate to say this Mac users, it might be experience but this is one area where I far prefer the PC OS.

Something which would help tremendously is a guide to all the click+drag+hotkey combinations. It isn't intuitive, there are many possible combinations, and there appears not be a definitive guide?

Ok, here's what I learned.

This is in the finder window, not the desktop:
Click alone: Swaps to the file/folder, eliminating other selections.
Click + cmd: Toggles the selection on that file folder, preserving other selections.
Click + option: Same as click alone?
Click + ctrl: Right click / context menu.
Click + fn: same as click alone?
Click + shift: Extend selection to file clicked.

Drag = Move.
Drag + cmd = Add to selection and move.
Drag + option = Copy.

Ok, stop! This will go on for a long time if I try every single possible permutation.

This began when I wanted to create an alias. It's so un-intuitive, I always feel like I'm starting from scratch. So, my first question was "How do I create an alias?".

I've discovered it since:

Cmd + Option + Drag.

Doesn't exactly throw itself at you, does it? Why this and not one of the other myriad key combinations? Esp when you consider that "shift + option + cmd + v" is paste without copying style. Again, a pretty usual thing to do when you paste.

This means there are potentially thousands of different key combinations.

Obviously, I know.

So the question is the basics then:

What are all the useful combinations of click and/or drag +/- keystroke for file operations on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Start with https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201236

Yes, there are more than you'll ever learn, & reading them all in a list is not the way to learn anything - but you pick the ones that are useful now, then go back if there's one you think ought to be there but you don't recall it.

It doesn't cover the 'click' or 'drag' options, but actually they're very simple.

**Clicks**

- Click - select something.
- <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  Click - add from first selected to current Click [note this is **not** cumulative, the first selected item is remembered, with the following caveat]
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  Click - non-contiguous selection [same as Win ctrl/click]
  Caveat - this also updates what is considered the 'first selected' in the previous bullet point.

**Drags**

- Drag itself will move if the same volume, or copy if to another [same as Win]
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  drag - to a different volume, will Move instead of Copy.
- <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  [or  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  , same key different label] drag - Create a copy [anywhere, same volume or different]
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  drag - make an alias.

<kbd>Fn</kbd>  does nothing in clicks or drags, it's used to alternate between true F-Key behaviour & built-in system controls like Volume up/down etc. It also adds missing functions on short keyboards [laptops etc] to access those available on full size keyboards - page up/down/home/end etc ...which are Fn + up/down/left/right arrows